# Django not recognising module import/ app folder

Tags: python, django

I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a48xeeo5Vnk&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=2) to learn some django. I have followed the tutorial and I get the following error: `NameError: name'blog' is not defined` when i try to run `django_project/urls.py`. My code is exactly the same as the tutorial- the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Django_Blog/02-Application-And-Routes/django_project).

My full error is:

[image]

My `django_project/urls.py` file is as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [ path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                path('', include(blog.urls)),]
```

My directory structure is as follows:

[image]

I am running Python 3.7 with Django 1.11.21 in the same directory as the manage.py file. I also have `__init__.py` in both the blog and django_project folder. I am using a linux VM. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: in your main urls you have to include the blog urls

Comment: @bmons sorry, can you clarify what you mean please? shouldn't python be able to find the `blog` module because it's in the same working directory?

Comment: please post your complete error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add '`blog`' inside `INSTALLED_APPS` at `settings.py`